# Retrieving data from a webpage that updates after the page loads

Tags: java, html, jsoup

There is a webpage I have been trying to access data from, but on the page load the div I need to access is empty and gets updated after like 1 second later. When I am reading the webpage with java it never reaches this point. I always get it to be empty (well its actually a placeholder text that gets overwritten, so I know I'm in the correct spot)

Is there a way to wait for it to load before I get it? Alternatively, how could I find out where the data thats being written to the page is coming from?

Current code:

```
public class AlchemyCalculator {

final int Max = 13192;
final int Min = 2;


    public static void main(String[] args){


        try {
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://rsbuddy.com/exchange/?id=2").get(); 
            String textContents = doc.select("#buy-price").outerHtml();
                     //was just ensuring I was at the right place by using outerHtml
            System.out.println(textContents);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

I'm just starting small to try and get it working once then I'm planning on expanding it.

Comment: post your current code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSoup is just a parser. It can also get the documents to parse directly from the internet with its connect() method, but it is not a browser. So if your site loads more resources later via AJAX, Jsoup can't handle it directly.

I see to choices:

- Use selenium, which is a real browser and therefore will create the AJAX calls you need
- Identify the AJAX calls by investigating what URL is actually called. maybe you can call those requests manually with JSoup.

I looked at the site. You might be lucky and all info can be retrieved from

```
https://rsbuddy.com/exchange/summary.json
```

To interpret this you should use a JSON parser, not Jsoup.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed, how did you go about finding it? I was looking through and couldn't find anything, and I searched the html for that url but it wasn't there.

Comment: Okay, I see it in the exchange.js file. Did you just get it by looking for it is there a special way?

Comment: No, I looked at the network traffic tab in the browser developer tools (F12 in chrome, Crtl+Shift+Q in Firefox)